# Unable to resolve service for type 'ISignalRHub' while attempting to activate 'NotificationController'

Tags: dependency-injection, signalr

My NET CORE 6 project working fine before I try to inject SignalR hub to controller.
My service definition

```
    Services.AddControllers(Sub(x) x.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = True).AddControllersAsServices
    Services.AddMvcCore(Sub(x) x.EnableEndpointRouting = False).AddFormatterMappings
    ....
    Services.AddSingleton(Of INotificationCacheService, NotificationCacheService)
    'SignalR
    Services.AddSignalR().
             AddHubOptions(Of NotificationHub)(Sub(options)
                                                  options.EnableDetailedErrors = True
                                               End Sub)
```

This injection to controller working fine

```
<ApiController>
<Route("[controller]/[action]")>
Public Class NotificationController
    Inherits ControllerBase
    Sub New(ByVal UserService As IUserService, Cryptor As IAesCryptor, DbContext As ApplicationDbContext, httpContextAccessor As IHttpContextAccessor, Logger As ILogger(Of NotificationController), Configuration As IConfiguration, NotificationService As INotificationCacheService)
```

But if I try to add SignalR hub to the controller

```
    Sub New(ByVal UserService As IUserService, Cryptor As IAesCryptor, DbContext As ApplicationDbContext, httpContextAccessor As IHttpContextAccessor, Logger As ILogger(Of NotificationController), Configuration As IConfiguration, NotificationService As INotificationCacheService, NotificationHub As INotificationHub)
```

I receive error:
Unable to resolve service for type 'INotificationHub' while attempting to activate 'NotificationController'.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this issue is very simple, need to inject to SignalR services to DI as scoped services, because adding SignalR service don't inject own implementation of service to DI container.

```
 Services.AddScoped(Of INotificationHub, NotificationHub)
```

Other small difficulties, if you refuse to use ancient languages from 60-x of previous century, because ancient language has no difference between Implements and Inherits, in dumb languages like C# this two opposite OOP idea mark as one character ":". And, of course, in ancient language one character always means absolutely different idea, for example "+" means accumulating value, concatenation string and even manipulation with events. At common, this is reason why Google create modern language KOTLIN (it looks as VB.NET), but unfortunately MS going backward to ancient language - C#.

So, if you want to use modern strong languages with strong meaning of each characters in you source code, you need define SignalR Hub in the same way (**Inherits AND Implements**), for example in my case

```
Public Interface INotificationHub
    Function NotifyClient(msg As ClientNotificationMessage) As Task
End Interface


Public Class NotificationHub
    Inherits Hub(Of INotificationHub)
    Implements INotificationHub
...
Public Sub New(...)
...
Public Async Function NotifyClient(Msg As ClientNotificationMessage) As Task Implements INotificationHub.NotifyClient
...
Public Overrides Async Function OnConnectedAsync() As Task
...
Public Overrides Async Function OnDisconnectedAsync
```